# script runs with 'bundler exec ruby script.rb' but fails when using 'ruby script.rb'

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler

I have a script that requires a gem that i'm getting from a private github repo with a specific branch (lets just call this gem `foobar`).

I'm using rvm, rails verson 2.3.0, and a gemset (lets call it testset). 
I'm using bundler to install my gems.

When I execute my script using `bundler exec ruby script.rb` it runs fine. However when I try running it using `ruby script.rb` I get the following error:

```
require': cannot load such file -- foobar (LoadError)
```

Its also worth noting that using only ruby works if I use the path to the gem as follows:

`require '~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testset/bundler/gems/foobar-a41fed1fcab7/lib/foobar.rb'`

Is there anyway I can use `ruby script.rb` while only using `require 'foobar`?

Comment: using bundle exec to run your script is a best practice. Otherwise you're going down a dark path of making sure that x amount of gems are available globally.

If you're trying to include a local file or gem then you'll have to
`require 'path/to/gem'`

Comment: wouldn't rvm solve this issue though? since i'm only making my packages available in specific gemsets?

Comment: To me it sounds like you're trying to accomplish the same thing with gemsets, which historically is problem prone, that you could do with bundler, worked out of the box for you.

I'm not totally sure what your RVM setup is like, but there are a lot of gotchas. `bundler exec` is a best practice because it's easy, it's reliable and everyone likes it. At the heart of it, it's a much more complex, yet vastly more elegant system than RVM gemsets.

If I were you I'd limit RVM usage to controlling only the Ruby version and the needed global gems. Have you heard of RBenv?

Comment: @Iwnnay no. I'm actually very new to ruby in general (hence the nooby question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use `bundle exec`, then `require` will work to require gems that are installed in your system gems. It will require the latest (larger number version) gem currently installed in the system; if no gems with that name are installed in the system, it will give you the LoadError.

(Note, `require` isn't *only* used for loading gems, it can also be used to load other files on the load path, but for the purpose of this question we're talking about it's ability to load gems).

You don't have the `foobar` gem installed on your system, so you get the LoadError.

So why does it work with `bundle exec`? bundler is a dependency management tool. When you use `bundle exec`, bundler loads the exact versions of gems you specified in your Gemfile/Gemfile.lock files, and makes them available to `require`. In this case, `require gemname` won't neccesarily load the latest version installed on your system, it will load exactly the version specified in the Gemfile.lock -- because `bundle exec` sets things up to do that.

Ordinarily bundler also installs all gems to the system location when you run `bundle install`.  But there are some cases where bundler installs the gems only "locally" in the current directory, and not in the general system gem location. One of these cases is if you *tell* it to with the `path` argument. But that's not what's going on for you. Another case is if you tell bundler to load a gem directly from a git repo, with the `:git` or `:github` arguments in a Gemfile. The general gem system isn't capable of loading gems directly from a git repo, that's only a bundler feature. So if you have something listed in your Gemfile with `:git` option, it will always only be installed for the local app, not in the system-wide gem location. I think that's what's going on in this case, the clue was the `gems/foobar-a41fed1fcab7` in the path of your example that works -- gems listed with something like `-a41fed1fcab7` on the end of their name are typically direct-from-git-repo gems, the `a41fed1fcab7` is a git SHA identifying exactly what version from the git repo is currently being used.

I can tell from your path that you are also using rvm gemsets, which complicates the matter a bit further, but this is confusing enough so I didn't go into that -- everything I wrote still stands, except "your system-wide gems" is really "the current rvm gemset".   Personally, I believe you'd be better off not using the rvm gemset feature -- things are confusing enough without it, and it isn't really needed anymore now that we have bundler, rvm gemsets were invented before bundler existed (several years ago). And I'm not totally sure why people keep using them now!

> Is there anyway I can use ruby script.rb while only using require 'foobar?

Sure. You just need to make sure `foobar` is installed to your system gems, with `gem install foobar`.  Then `require "foobar"` will load the *latest* version installed to your system gems.  (But you can only install *released* gems with specific version numbers to your system gems, not arbitrary checkouts from git). What if you want to load a specific version? Well, you *can* do something like `gem 'foobar', "1.0.2"` instead of `require 'foobar'`.  But with a list of gem dependencies that are at all non-trivial, you will soon start to get into a terrible mess of managing exactly what version of a gem you are using is compatible with what version of another gem you are using. As well as setting up a new system and figuring out exactly what version of gems you need to install from scratch to work with `script.rb`.  It becomes a real mess. It is for this that `bundler` was invented, and you'd be wise to use it.

(Although sure, you *could* use rvm gemsets instead of bundler -- but not with gems installed direct from git, only bundler supports that, at least without a lot of manual hackery, and rvm gemsets aren't very good when it comes to setting up a new system from scratch, bundle solves that a lot better).

If you *do* have a Gemfile and Gemfile.lock in the same directory as `script.rb` (as you seem to), and you just want to avoid having to write `bundle exec`, you can just put this at the top of `script.rb` (before any other `require`s!):

```
 require 'bundler'
 Bundler.setup
```

That basically just tells bundler to do the equivalent of `bundle exec` when `script.rb` is run, without actually having to write `bundle exec`. Then you can just run `ruby script.rb` (or even `./script.rb`), and it'll still do the same thing as `bundle exec`, but without having to write it on the command line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, I honestly asked this question because I didn't see a solid answer for it anywhere else, this explains everything very well. Thank you